# Private Variables in Function Expressions

Tags: javascript, private, public

Why does this not work?

```
(function () {
    var cache = ['hii'];
    return function add (fn) {
         if (!cache.contains(fn)) {
              cache.push(fn);
              return true;
         }
         return false;
    };
}());

add('dd');
```

I am getting an error that says: **Uncaught referenceError: add is not defined.**

Comment: because it is not global... that return does nothing...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Interesting example of function expression vs function declaration, disguising itself as a scope issue.

See this example

```
var x=function y() {return 1;};
console.log(x()); //1
console.log(y()); //ReferenceError: y is not defined
```

You could revise your code to this and it would work, because you are now assigning the function to the variable add, which is implicitly global:

```
(function () {
    var cache = ['hii'];
    return add = function (fn) {
         if (!cache.contains(fn)) {
              cache.push(fn);
              return true;
         }
         return false;
    };
}());

add('dd'); //true
```

If it were this, then it would be a scope issue:

```
(function () {
    var cache = ['hii'];
    var add;
    return add=function (fn) {
         if (!cache.contains(fn)) {
              cache.push(fn);
              return true;
         }
         return false;
    };
}());

add('dd'); //ReferenceError: add is not defined
```

Comment: Hi anyways in case anyone else is interested here is the contains method that I was using:Array.prototype.contains = function(obj) {
    var i = this.length;
    while (i--) {
        if (this[i] === obj) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
};

Answer (score 2):

The outer anonymous function returns the inner `add` function, but the return value isn't assigned to anything, so you can't access it.

(Note that giving `add` a name doesn't mean it'll be available by that name; because it's part of the `return` statement it becomes a [function expression](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions_and_function_scope#Function_constructor_vs._function_declaration_vs._function_expression) which, confusingly, has the same syntax as a function declaration but doesn't result in a variable being created pointing to that function.)

Try changing the first line to look like this:

```
add = (function () {
```

Answer (score 1):

Try naming the IIFE:

```
var foo = (function () {
  var cache = ['hii'];
  return function add (fn) {
     if (!cache.contains(fn)) {
          cache.push(fn);
          return true;
     }
     return false;
  };
 }());

foo('dd');
```

An alternative way of calling an IIFE is to parameterize it:

```
(function () {
  var cache = ['hii'];
  return function add (fn) {
     if (!cache.contains(fn)) {
          cache.push(fn);
          return true;
     }
     return false;
  };
 }('dd')); //<--params here
```

Comment: that is not the case here. it is because it is a function expression, as Adam Brenecki says, it is not an issue of scope.